# Child $stateParams empty object in state.resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**This issue is in ui-router 1.0.0-alpha.4**

Related plunker: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tnQZWcKCfn7iVZANrOHC?p=preview)

I need parent state URL parameter to be available in state declaration resolve. Currently I am trying to fetch these from $state.params or $stateParams but seems they do not work consistently.

The plunker example demonstrates similar state tree as I currently have in my application. The problem is when transitioning from `home.list` to `home.foo.bar({ id: 1 })`. The abstract state `home.foo` resolve shows correctly `$stateParams = { id: 1}` but the child state `home.foo.bar` shows only empty object.

Furthermore, `$state.params` is also empty object BUT shows correctly after the resolve block is completed. The value is bind to the view in the example.

Am I doing something wrong or should I report this as an issue? This worked before in 0.2.x, and happened when I wanted to start using 1.0 version.